# Solve non-linear equation using nleqslv package in R

Tags: r, solver, non-linear

I am new to R and I am trying to solve a non-linear equation. The equation is a function of 4 variables: `Q`, `D`, `E2+z`, and `y1.new`. I have values for `Q`, `D`, and `E2+z` stored in individual vectors with length=3364. For each of these cases, I want to find y1.new that satisfies the equation below

```
0 =  `y1.new` + (`Q`/((`D`^2)/8)*(2*acos(1-2*`y1.new`/`D`) - sin(2*acos(1-2*`y1.new`/`D`))))^2/(2*9.81) - `E2+z`.
```

I set a function as

```
target.y1.new <- function(y1.new, Q=Q,D=D,`E2+z`=`E2+z`,g=9.81)
{
  y <- numeric(1)
  y[1] <- `y1.new` + (`Q`/((`D`^2)/8)*(2*acos(1-2*`y1.new`/`D`) - sin(2*acos(1-2*`y1.new`/`D`))))^2/(2*`g`) - `E2+z`
}
```

my initial guesses are stored in a vector named `y1`, also with 3364 values

I tried to use the function

```
nleqslv(`y1`,`target.y1.new`,control=list(btol=0.01),jacobian=TRUE)
```

but it results in an error

> Error in fn(par, ...) :
> promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance,
Benny

Comment: `E2+z` cannot be a variable. When I try the definition of your function `target.y1.new` the following error is given: `Error: unexpected '+' in "target.y1.new <- function(y1.new, Q=Q,D=D,E2+"`

Comment: You have backticks where they are not needed and a variable with a plus sign in its name. Simplify your naming code and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rui is right. You are using backticks where they are not needed.

Simplifying and correction your function `target.y1.new` results in this

```
target.y1.new <- function(y1.new,g=9.81)
{
  y <- numeric(length(y1.new))
  y <- y1.new + (Q/((D^2)/8)*(2*acos(1-2*y1.new/D) - sin(2*acos(1-2*y1.new/D))))^2/(2*g) - E2pz
  y
}
```

You say you have vectors of length 3364. Your function works with vectors. This means that your function should return a vector of length 3364 which is why the definition of the return value `y` should have the same length as the input vectors.

With some trial values we can try this

```
Q <- c(1,2)
D <- c(1,2)
E2pz <- c(1,2)
y1 <- rep(.1,2)
```

You can now do the following

```
nleqslv(y1,target.y1.new,control=list(btol=0.01),jacobian=TRUE)
```

This will give you a solution.
But it is not the most efficient. You system of equations is diagonal in the sense that the input `y` of any equation does not occur in any other equation.

`nleqslv` has an option for a specifying a band (including diagonal) jacobian (see the manual). As follows

```
nleqslv(y1,target.y1.new,control=list(btol=0.01,dsub=0,dsuper=0),
        jacobian=TRUE,method="Newton")
```

In this case  it is better to use the Newton method since the default Broyden method will do too much work. And it does not work with a diagonal jacobian.

Comment: That is a great explanation, thanks Bhas. Sorry for my ignorance on the topic, but would it be better if I expressed the system of equations in multiple ones instead of a single one? I can write the equations as  target.y1.new <- function(y1.new,g=9.81)
{
  y <- numeric(length(y1.new))
  teta1.new <- 2*acos(1-2*y1.new/D)
  A1.new <- ((D^2)/8)*(teta1.new - sin(teta1.new))
  V1.energy.new <- (Q/A1.new)^2
  y <- y1.new + V1.energy.new/(2*g) - E2pz

}

Comment: I would leave it as is. You can use it for one or more equations without changing. If you do it for a single equation you will have to use vector indexing to solve  equations one by one. Which is not necessary here.